# Fire event on Jquery check/uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I want to set a variable (pageselected) as per the checkbox `click/unclick` event.

#### The HTML code is :

```
<thead>
    <tr id="othercheckbox">
        <th width="10"><input type="checkbox" name="zip" class="all"  value="all" /></th>              
    </tr>
</thead>
```

#### The code in JS file is :

```
$('#othercheckbox').click(function() {

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log("CCCCheckeddddddd");
        that.pageselected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("UNCheckeddddddd");
        that.pageselected = false;
    }
}
```

But this is not behaving as expected. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Table rows don't have a checked property.

Comment: It is a variable used in the code declared as
var that = e.data.that ;
so we refer all the user-defined variables as that.<variable_name>

Comment: Thanks. Then where should I add the id ?

Answer (score 13):

You are checking the row is checked or not, which is not possible.bind `onchange` event on the checkbox. put it on the checkbox let say checkbox1.

#### HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="zip" id="checkbox1" class="all"  value="all" />
```

#### JS Script:

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log("CCCCheckeddddddd");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("UNCheckeddddddd");
    }    

});
```

Comment: I would remove `that` since it is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n0Lp0ou8/1/)***

Since the checkbox is inside the `tr` with id `othercheckbox` .. Use this

```
$('#othercheckbox input[name="zip"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("CCCCheckeddddddd");
        //that.pageselected = true;
    } else {
        alert("UNCheckeddddddd");
        //that.pageselected = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector. Bind the event on the input rather on tr. If you only want to set `true` or `false` then following approach will be better.

**JS:**

```
$('#othercheckbox input').click(function () {        
    var pageselected = $(this).is(':checked'); // change pageselected or any variable of your choice accordingly.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/329/